# GRUB command line. Have to boot manually

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, grub, uefi

Somehow my grub got corrupted while updating my Pop!_OS System. I rewrote the partition, grub-install, boot-repair, I tried anything.

Well, I can boot by typing the following lines.

```
set prefix=(hd1,gpt3)/boot/grub
set root=(hd1,gpt3)
insmod normal
normal
```

But I can't get grub to do it automatically. It's not "that bad", but it's really annoying to type that down everytime I boot.

Is there any config File I can use to "automate" that stuff again?
Thank you in advise!

**

> EDIT: I tried update-grub, grub-install. Various methods, I just don't
> get it.

**

Here's some basic information:

Kernel: 5.19.0-76051900-generic

Partitions:

```
/dev/md0p3       /
/dev/md0p4       /home
/dev/md0p1       /boot/efi
```

Here is a tree of my /boot directory:

```
.
├── config-5.18.10-76051810-generic
├── config-5.19.0-76051900-generic
├── efi
│   ├── EFI
│   │   ├── BOOT
│   │   │   ├── bkpbootx64.efi
│   │   │   └── bootx64.efi
│   │   ├── pop
│   │   │   ├── grub.cfg
│   │   │   └── grubx64.efi
│   │   ├── pop_os
│   │   │   ├── grub.cfg
│   │   │   └── grubx64.efi
│   │   └── Pop_OS-f8340379-32a0-45b0-82fa-f157f426bd50
│   │       ├── cmdline
│   │       ├── initrd.img
│   │       ├── initrd.img-previous
│   │       ├── vmlinuz.efi
│   │       └── vmlinuz-previous.efi
│   └── loader
│       ├── entries
│       │   ├── Pop_OS-current.conf
│       │   └── Pop_OS-oldkern.conf
│       └── loader.conf
├── grub
│   ├── fonts
│   │   └── unicode.pf2
│   ├── grub.cfg
│   ├── grubenv
│   ├── locale
        # Tons of locale-files
│   │   └── zh_TW.mo
│   ├── unicode.pf2
│   └── x86_64-efi
│       #Tons of .mod files
│       ├── xzio.mod
│       ├── zfscrypt.mod
│       ├── zfsinfo.mod
│       ├── zfs.mod
│       └── zstd.mod
├── grub.bak
│   ├── grub.cfg
│   └── grubenv
├── initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.19.0-76051900-generic
├── initrd.img-5.17.5-76051705-generic-nouveau
├── initrd.img-5.18.10-76051810-generic
├── initrd.img-5.19.0-76051900-generic
├── initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.18.10-76051810-generic
├── System.map-5.18.10-76051810-generic
├── System.map-5.19.0-76051900-generic
├── vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.19.0-76051900-generic
├── vmlinuz-5.18.10-76051810-generic
├── vmlinuz-5.19.0-76051900-generic
└── vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.18.10-76051810-generic
```

Comment: I think that entry you are manually typing should be in `grub.cfg`.  I see you have three copies of that (two is normal).  Looks like maybe you have a duplicate in EFI, one of those is probably stale, and I'd bet the stale one is the default.  Try changing your boot order; check file dates and maybe delete the duplicate (after changing boot order).

Comment: Have you updated grub? run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: The sudo update-grub updates menu. You may need a reinstall & then menu update. Try `sudo grub-install` If UEFI & correct ESP - efi system partition is in fstab (check mount if changing) & you have been able to manually boot no extra mount or parameters required. I show a reinstall on my sytem: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2478104 If not booted into system,  you many need chroot or Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd suggest you create a new grub cfg file by typing as a root user:

```
grub2-mkconfig –o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

then, again as root user

```
update-grub2
```

> Note: if `update-grub2` is not present use `update-grub`

Comment: Yea, tried that and didn't work, same results

Comment: @Ven then I think you need to set a default booting kernel in your OS

Answer (score 0):

To define a new boot option for the new kernel you have installed, go to the (/boot/loader/entries) directory with root access and create a new file with the extension .conf and name this file the same as the name of the newly installed kernel, for example:
ef8547eded9a4d-5.19.0-76051900-generic.conf

And then write your desired settings inside this file.

*Below is an example of the settings for you:*

```
title PopOs(Workstation)

version 5.19.0-76051900-generic

linux /vmlinuz-5.19.0-76051900-generic

initrd /initrd.img-5.19.0-76051900-generic

options root=UUID=52d3d64b-5de1-4483-9fd9-e171b7acdbe9 ro 

resume=UUID=0cb3dec1-cce5-46d6-89b6>

grub_users $grub_users

grub_arg --unrestricted
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I was trying to create a Xubuntu distribution on a USB disk. I tried the `sudo update-grub` option given above and it didn't work. The fix for me was to boot into linux using the commands you suggest except that my root partition was (hd2,gpt2) and then I had to reinstall the grub bootloader. I used `lsblk` to find the name of my boot device which was  `/dev/nvme1n1` and then I used the install command:

`sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/boot /dev/nvme1n1`

I expect all this could also be done from a live Ubuntu USB disk too if there are difficulties getting linux to boot from the grub command line (finding the right disk can be tricky if you have a lot of disks). You can mount the hard disk and change the command to point to the mounted location of the boot directory.